# Placing the comment area last

Tags: php, wordpress, textarea

I want to place the comment textarea at the bottom and not the top. I am using a theme but do not understand where in the php to re-arrange them so it is at the bottom.

can anyone help?

```
<?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
<div class="row">
 <div class="blog-span">                            
<?php  
 $fields=array(
    'author' => '<div class="form-group clearfix"><label class="control-label col-xs-2" id="name">Name *</label><div class="col-xs-6"><input required class="form-control" name="author" id="author" value="" type="text"/></div></div>',
    'email' => '<div class="form-group clearfix"><label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="user-email" id="user-email"> E-mail *</label><div class="col-xs-6"><input  required class="form-control" name="email" id="user-email" value=""   type="text" ></div></div>',
    'website' => '<div class="form-group clearfix"><label class="control-label col-xs-2" for="website_url" id="website_url">Website</label><div class="col-xs-6"><input class="form-control" name="website_url" id="website_url" value=""   type="text" ></div></div>',
    );
function my_fields($fields) { 
    return $fields;
}
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','my_fields');
    $defaults = array(
    'fields'=> apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', $fields ),
    'comment_field'=> '<div class="form-group clearfix"><label for="message" class="control-label col-xs-2"> Message *</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8"><textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="form-control"></textarea></div></div><div class="space-sep-10"></div>',      
    'logged_in_as' => '<p class="logged-in-as">' . __( "Logged in as ",'weblizar' ).'<a href="'. admin_url( 'profile.php' ).'">'.$user_identity.'</a>'. '<a href="'. wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ).'" title="Log out of this account">'.__(" Log out?",'weblizar').'</a>' . '</p>',

    'class_submit' => 'btn btn-primary',
    'label_submit'=>__( 'Send','weblizar'),
    'comment_notes_before'=> '',
    'comment_notes_after'=>'<div class="form-group clearfix"><label class="control-label col-xs-2"></label><div class="col-xs-6">                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send">                </div>
        </div>',
    'title_reply'=> '<div class="title-block clearfix"><h3 class="h3-body-title">Leave A Comment</h3><div class="title-seperator"></div></div>',
    'id_form'=> 'comment-form',
    'class_form'=> 'form-wrapper'
    );
    comment_form($defaults); ?>     
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('comment_form_fields', function($fields)
{
    $textarea = $fields['comment'];
    unset($fields['comment']);
    $fields['comment'] = $textarea;
    return $fields;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dan :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 comment_form($defaults); ?>
```

U need to place this outside ur div. So all the way on the bottom of ur code.